# Creating a new window/Tab

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I want to open a link in a new tab, equivalent to the: `target=_blank"`
But instead of opening a new tab/window, which in my case can result in the user (old people that are bad with tech) not knowing that a new window opened, I want to open a smaller window, on top of the current window/page. This is so that the user sees the new window easily.
Is there a nice way to do this?
This can either be in code behind, or client code, it doesn't matter for me

Comment: window.open() accepts arguments to specify the size of the new window. get the size of the current window, and make the new window smaller than that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Add this on the page that will open up.
    alert('New window opened!');
</script>
```

How about a simple alert?